How to properly set the transaction locks
The documentation at MSDN for "Set Transaction Isolation Level" lists 4 different isolation levels.
I read through them, but I prefer to learn by example, so the explanation is not good for me.
Could someone give me an example of those 4 differences?
I need to exclusively run:
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST foo();
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXIST foo_x ON foo();
INSERT INTO foo VALUES();
COMMIT/ROLLBACK

I need to do that inside {exclusive} transaction and only once, so nobody else will do that.
Those commands will run inside C++ app and in the end of the day only 1 table with 1 unique index exist and it will contain only 1 set of records 1 connection.
EDIT:
If I ran my app from 2 different machines I need to do a proper lock so that only one table can be created, only one index can be created, and only 1 set of records can be inserted into the table.
As a sole developer I can't test this scenario...
But the documentation is not explaining it either and there is no example on any of the 4.

None of that code is even compilable, nor do we understand what you are trying to lock against, is someone else executing stuff at the same time? Anyway, best posted on [dba.se] with more detail.

The first half of your question is not suitable for this site. Its your job to do the research and then ask a specific question when stuck.

@Charlieface, I edited the OP and hopefully it makes it better understandable,,,

For that sort of thing you can just use sp_getapplock

@DaleK, iit is about programming, so why it is not suited?

Your question starts with "Could someone give me an example of those 4 differences?" - which is too broad. Its not a specific issue - which is required for this site.

@DaleK, I tried to google, but received the link to the same documentation page where there is no example on what the difference is,,,

@DaleK, can I use sp_getapplock() to get a lock on the DB? My understanding is that I will need that for CREATE TABLE

@DaleK, it absolutely does not. I need an example with the explanation on how it works in every lock... Put in some table schema and then for each one say: If one connection writes data second will/will not be able to read/write to the same table. And what about CREATE... statements? On SQL Server they can be part of the transaction and so will probably be affected. Or not? And f yes - how?

And what about reading/writing to a different table

So the documentation is clear, getapplock doesn't take locks on individual objects/tables... it takes a lock on a block of code. So for example if you put your code in question in a stored procedure, use getapplock within the stored procedure, you can be sure that only one instance of your app can run it at a time. Unless you are making these sort of changes from random places in your code, this is all you need to ensure that this particular block of code runs only once.

Why are you running CREATE TABLE from multiple machines anyway? it's not the sort of thing you should do regularly, you would change the schema only at specific downtime intervals. I still don't know what exactly you are trying to protect against. Is it only creating the table/index once (IF NOT EXISTS will protect that) Is it only inserting once (depends what other constructs are in the INSERT such as WHERE NOT EXISTS)?  Is it just that database won't get corrupted (it won't, you just might get blocking)?

@DaleK App-lock is not necessary here. CREATE TABLE will take a Sch-M locko n the database, which will last until the COMMIT, so every other execution of the same code will block on the first line.

@Charlieface, yes. Trying to make them only once and make sure that when I populate the tables it happens only once. If I install the app on 2 different machines and run it simultaneously I could end up up with deadlock or multiple copies of the data. If I want to populate the table with different masks/fonts/formats for data editing, it needs to be put only once

You won't get deadlocks... thats not how they work. As Charlieface says it will only run once, because the first run will take a Sch-M lock and prevent it running again concurrently.

@DaleK, what about data population?

Change your insert to insert values() when not exists ()

I'll be honest: an actual example would be useful as none of this code actually works at all at the moment. CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST isn't valid in SQL Server anyway, you need to use other methods such as IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects etc

@DaleK, I dont see that syntax anywhere on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16.

@Charlieface, apologies for that - you are right. I am using IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'table_name' AND xtype = 'U') CREATE TABLE table_name()

@Igor did you see you have an answer below?

Just use sp_getapplock. Note that noone (besides you probably) does this on a table level, usually its single rows in already created tables, so I'm assuming you're doing something wrong/strange

As long as the first line of the code in between BEGIN TRAN and COMMIT is CREATE TABLE then a Sch-M schema-lock is taken on the whole database, preventing anyone else from changing it. So it's not possible for someone else to run the same code concurrently anyway. Sch-M locks are taken in all isolation levels, and are always held until the end of the transaction.
But CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS is not valid in SQL Server anyway. What you would get, if you tried to run a normal CREATE TABLE, is one session succeeding, and the other failing with an error on a duplicate table name. If that's what you want then great.
But to avoid an error, instead you need something like this (note the explicit SERIALIZABLE, UPDLOCK hints to force the locking to work correctly).
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRAN;

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM sys.objects o WITH (SERIALIZABLE, UPDLOCK)
    WHERE o.name = 'foo'
)
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE dbo.foo (
        columnsHere,
        UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX foo_x (columnsHere)
    );

    INSERT INTO foo (columnsHere)
    SELECT colsHere
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM dbo.foo .....
    );

END;

COMMIT;

